# What do these Mahabharatha shlokas mean and which part of the epic do they come from?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request

So, both of these shlokas are used in the bollywood movie [Vaastav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaastav:_The_Reality). I deduced that these shlokas must have come from Mahabharatha and not the Geeta because I felt it is inconsistent with the Geeta narration.

I googled the shlokas and did not find any useful information about them. Now, I say Mahabharatha because, I, strongly and vehemently refuse to believe that a bollywood lyricist could have come up with these lyrics. Impossible. Should be from Vyasa. Also, both these shlokas, may not appear one after the other in the epic because they're describing events that happened, easily, 16 years apart.

> Shree Krishnena Subhadraaye, Garbhavatye nirupitam.  Chakravyuh
>   Praveshasya Rahasyam Chakutam hitat. Abhimanyu Stitho Garbhe,
>   Divya gyanayuto Shruno. Rahasyam Chakravyuhasya Sampurnam na satyaatavan.

This [shloka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsggKLkQ4W4), I can summarize, is talking about Krishna narrating the solution to the chakravyuha to a pregnant Subhadra and an embryo Abhimanyu listening to it, but, only to the half of it.

> Yadaarjuno Gato dooram, Yodhumsamshaptadaisah. Abhimanyum vinananyah,
>   Samarthoyovyuhabhedane. Bheditechakravyuhepi, Atha eva veeryavaan.
>   Parthaputrasya Ekaki, Kauravair Nirkrunerhataha.

This [shloka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x6clW4WiVQ) is talking about how when Arjuna was far away, the young Abhimanyu, alone pierced into the Chakravyuha and was slain mercilessly by the Kauravas.

These two shlokas, may not appear one after the other in the epic (if at all they appear) given the amount of time between the two events.

What I ask the community here of course is the source of this shlokas, the number, the parva and the chapter, so that I may find it in the epic and read the translation for it.